# Error al usar d3: "d3 is not defined"

Tags: javascript, html, python, d3.js

Estoy comenzando a hacer mis pininos con `d3` en `Python` (usando `Jupyter`), con algo muy sencillo, pero sin importar lo que haga, tengo errores. 
Va el código:

```
from IPython.core.display import HTML, Javascript
import json

#Llamo a d3 desde el directorio donde trabajo (bajé el zip y lo instalé en una carpeta)

HTML('''<script src="d3/d3.min.js"></script>''')
```

Ahora viene lo que se supone debe hacerse: un letrero que diga "Hello D3!" en letras color naranja

```
HTML('''
<style scoped>
.bedazzled {
  color: orange;
}
</style>
<div id="d3-div-1"></div>
<script>

var size_data = [10,20,30];

d3.select("#d3-div-1").selectAll('.bedazzled')
    .data(size_data)
    .enter().append('p')
      .attr("class","bedazzled")
      .style("font-size", function(d){ return "" + d + "px";})
      .text("Hello D3!");

</script>
''')
```

El error que tengo es:

```
Javascript error adding output!
ReferenceError: d3 is not defined
See your browser Javascript console for more details.
```

He intentado incorporando `<script src="d3/d3.min.js"></script>` directamente en el código largo y en el primer llamado a `HTML` (primer bloque de código de este post),  usando `<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>` e incluso `<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min"></script>` con exactamente el mismo resultado.

Como podrán imaginar, estoy algo frustrado con este asunto, así que cualquier sugerencia la agradeceré infinitamente.

Comment: Proba usando esto: <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script> por lo que lei en los foros al error de d3 is not define lo solucionan asi https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21381097/d3-is-not-defined-referenceerror

Comment: @Juan Olvidé mencionar que esa solución también ya la intenté. He intentado muchas soluciones y ninguna funciona. No sé qué esté fallando...

Comment: Ahi te dice que vayas a la consola que te sale ahi? Click derecho sobre la pagina -> Inspeccionar -> console

Comment: Tambien podes ver "Ver codigo fuente" para ver donde entra el script ya que tiene que cargarse primero para que tu funcion funcione

Comment: Lo chequé y sigo sin observar dónde está el error... :S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Encontré esta respuesta en SO en ingles https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44349183/cant-run-d3js-to-a-website-jupyter-notebook

Al parecer tienes que importar d3 globalmente utilizando este código:

```
%%javascript
require.config({
    paths: {
        d3: "https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min"
     }
});

require(["d3"], function(d3) {
    window.d3 = d3;
});
```

Lo probé y me funciona

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Rayos. Esa solución no la había encontrado y mira que le di vuelta a medio SO. ¡Gracias!